# Continuity of the dual product reloaded

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space with topological dual $X^*$. Then the dual product $(x,x^*)\in X\times X^*\to x^*(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ is strongly$\times$strongly continuous in $X\times X^*$.

That does not hold if the topology considered on $X^*$ is the weak-star topology and the space is non-reflexive. Let $\tau^*_M$ the Mackey topology on $X^*$ with respect to the duality $(X^*,X)$. Then

$X$ is reflexive iff the dual product is strongly$\times\tau^*_M$ (lower)(upper)(semi-)continuous.

My question is:

$\ \ Q:\ $ If $X$ is a Banach non-reflexive space what is the coarsest topology $\tau$ on the dual $X^*$ for which the dual product is strongly$\times\tau$ continuous in $X\times X^*$?

Clearly $\tau$ is weaker than the strong topology on $X^*$ and finer than $\tau^*_M$.

Comment: It's not true that the dual product is strongly$\times$weakly-star continuous if $X$ is a(n infinite dimensional) reflexive Banach space. If it is strongly$\times\tau$-continuous, then $\{(x,x^\ast) : \lvert x^\ast(x)\rvert \leqslant 1\}$ is a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$, hence there exist open neighbourhoods $U,V$ of $0$ in the respective spaces such that $\lvert x^\ast(x)\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all $(x,x^\ast)\in U\times V$. $U$ contains a ball $\overline{B_\varepsilon(0)}$, hence $V\subset \overline{B_{1/\varepsilon}(0)}$, and $\tau$ must be _at least as fine_ as the norm topology on $X^\ast$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right. I modified it so it holds. It seems that your argument also holds for non-reflexive spaces. Please write it as an answer.